# Entering Subdivision option and increasing the number of cuts on a plane

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface

How can I enter the subdivision option?

I have tried right clicking and it only moves the object around.
I want to use the subdivision options to increase the number of cuts on a plane.

Comment: Switch your object to Edit mode, select all and right click > Subdivide?

Comment: And then change the level of subdivision in the Operator Box